# Render photos like Pinterest

Tags: html, css, image, pinterest

Right now, pictures are rendered like this on my Ruby on Rails app.

[image]

The pictures are based on a table, whose each row has five cells, and each cell has specified padding as shown above. As you can see, this is a bit awkward looking and I want to make this look like below (from Pinterest)
[image]

The layout doesn't have to be exactly the same, but you see the point. I want the padding between each picture adjusted nicely.
From browsing Stackoverflow, I learned using [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/index.html) might be the perfect solution but I wonder if there is any other option because I want to avoid as much as possible from using jquery in my application.

**UPDATE:**

```
<div id="user_posts">
    <table>
    <% @posts.in_groups_of(5).each do |post_array| %>
        <tr>
        <% post_array.each do |post| %>
            <% unless post.blank? %>
            <td class="user_post_space"><%= link_to image_tag(post.image_url(:thumb), :class => "img-polaroid"), post %></td>
            <% end %>
        <% end %>
        </tr>
    <% end %>
    </table>
</div>
```

Thank you for your help in advance!

Comment: Polaroid flourishes aside, all you really need are columns striping content blocks at a fixed width and a variable block height. You could do this with `display: table` on a container and `display: table-cell`, six across, and make the container `height: 100%`. You just have to be conscious of the manner that you lay the stripes in markup, since they will be turned in a markup-to-layout sense.

Comment: You also probably want to keep track of the height of each column as you add new items to keep things relatively balanced.

Comment: I need some clarification. On what div do I set `display:table`, and on what container do I set `height: 100%`? I updated my code if you need it. Thanks!

Comment: I create a demo like this days ago, check this out here:  http://pi.zhuangya.me/demo/waterfall/

Comment: Well... You really should refactor the *actual* `table` elements out of your layout. `table`s are for tabular data; they shouldn't be used for layout. What I suggested, though, was actually just the CSS style property to have an element mimic the display characteristics of a `table`. I'll see if I can toss together a demo to show you what I meant. Also, [960.gs](http://960.gs/) is a CSS-only responsive grid-based layout. You could use it (or Bootstrap) and use 12 columns, each physical column spanning two columns.

Comment: Oh hey, look what I came across: http://bootstrapdesigner.com/DEMO/Easy_Start/grid.html

Comment: @JaredFarrish Thanks a lot. This is exactly what I've been looking for. Do I just study the demo page's source to apply to my website?

Comment: Well, I'm sure they'd like you pay for it... This was about halfway as far as I got last night on the approach I was referencing: http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/RVkJd/ I pulled it apart to do some other things, though, so the code right now is in pieces. I was trying to work out how to get the different lists to load different results so it could be tested, in other words.

Comment: Here's some other [very nice Bootstrap templates](https://wrapbootstrap.com/), which are pretty cheap; make sure and browser through the demos, especially the admin templates. Plus some skeleton templates (without all the specific views) are available through http://bootswatch.com/. Bootstrap has the grid setup, you just have to orient it up and down instead of right-left.

Answer (score 4):

i think  Use Jquery Masonry plugin it will make the layout like pinterest

```
http://masonry.desandro.com/
```

Comment: I'm already aware of this and the question was if there was any better option. Thanks for your input though!